# Header guard issues with circular #include

Tags: c++, header, include, circular-dependency, include-guards

I am making a small C++ framework, which contains many .h and .cpp.

I have created a general include which include all my .h file such as:

```
framework.h

#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"
```

each .h header are protected with include guard such as

```
#ifndef A_HEADER
#define A_HEADER
...
#endif
```

The issues is, I would like to be able to include "framework.h" inside all the sub .h such as, but it cause lots of compiler error:

```
#ifndef A_HEADER
#define A_HEADER

#include "framework.h"
...
#endif
```

If instead I use the real header file for each sub header, and the framework.h for what ever use my framework it works fine..

I would just like to include the main header inside all my sub .h so I dont need to include all the dependency everytime.

Thanks :)

Comment: What are the errors you get? It should work if the files are correct

Comment: Maybe you forgot the quotes in the includes in framework.h?

Comment: No circular dependency issues, but undefine stuff, just like it if I forgot to include a .h. Mosty for thing are are defined inline in some header files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically what your doing is `#include "A.h"` in framework.h and `#include "framework.h"` in A.h. This causes cyclic dependency of the header files and you will get errors such as undefined class A. To solve this, use forward declarations in header file and `#include` only in corresponding cpp file. If that is not possible then I don't see any other option other than including individual header files.

Answer (score 2):

You should not including the main header file inside the sub-header files. It should be used to make user's life easier, not yours.

Instead do following:

1) Make forward definitions of all you need in the related sub-header files.

2) Include only needed sub-header files inside CPP files.

3) When using your framework inside an application code (for example), then you could include the main framework header file.

Answer (score 1):

Just protect the main header with include guards too:

```
#ifndef FRAMEWORK_H
#   define FRAMEWORK_H
#   include <A.h>
#   include <B.h>
#   include <C.h>
#endif
```

That will prevent recursive inclusion.

Comment: No circular dependency issues, but undefine stuff, just like it if I forgot to include a .h. Mosty for thing are are defined inline in some header files.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend using [#pragma once](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once), and placing that at the top of all of your header files (framework.h, A.h, B.h, and C.h).

Although, if you'd rather, I think you could fix your problem by simply putting an include guard in framework.h as well.

Comment: Please don't use #pragma once in frameworks, we ordinary folk hate those deprecation warnings from g++.

Comment: Not an issue anymore. From Wikipedia:
"However, with the 3.4 release of GCC, the #pragma once handling code was fixed to behave correctly with symbolic and hard links. The feature was "un-deprecated" and the warning removed"

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a dependency between - say B and C such that B depends on C, but in framework.h C is included after B.

Answer (score 0):

Circular includes are generally a bad idea in C++. While having header guards will prevent the preprocessor from going into infinite loop (or throwing an error because of this), you will get unexpected compiler errors, because at some point a header file will not be included when if you think it is.

You should include `A.h`, `B.h` and `C.h` from `framework.h`, and in `A.h`, do not include `framework.h`, just forward declare the classes you use from it. Or do it the other way around: include `framework.h` from `A.h`, `B.h` and `C.h`, and forward declare classes in `framework.h`. And, of course, put every code that would require any more detailed declarations than for example `class A` to the .cpp files.